# CI/CD in gitlab through mirror repository

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci

I have been wanting to set up a CI/CD pipeline for a repository in its mirror repository. I have found articles on how to mirror a repo but I cannot find how to set up CI/CD in it and view the results in original repo. Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> how to set up CI/CD

It's the same approach as if without mirroring - you just add `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to your original git repository, it gets mirrored to GitLab which then runs pipelines for you

> how to ... view the results in original repo

You didn't specify where you host your original repo.
If it's a GitHub, then you will see GitLab pipelines on your GitHub Pull Requests.
It's the same as with any other CI tool integrated with GitHub.

[image]

Links:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/github_integration.html

Comment: What if I would store the original repo in GitLab itself?

Comment: Does the original repo in GitLab belongs to you? Can you add `.gitlab-ci.yml` there?

Comment: Those links work only for the premium edition.